# regex to read space delimited values in c#

Tags: c#, regex

code sample:

```
                string flowValues = @"(?<day>\d{2})\s+(?<val1>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val2>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)?\s+(?<val3>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val4>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)?\s+(?<val5>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val6>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)?\s+(?<val7>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val8>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val9>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)?\s+(?<val10>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val11>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)?\s+(?<val12>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)";
                regex = new Regex(flowValues, regexOptions);
                inputData = "30     64.0          96.6    101    172    258    647    612    599    184   74.8   63.0";//fileContents[10 + i];
                match = regex.Match(inputData);
                dataMatrix[i, 0] = match.Groups["val1"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 1] = match.Groups["val2"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 2] = match.Groups["val3"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 3] = match.Groups["val4"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 4] = match.Groups["val5"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 5] = match.Groups["val6"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 6] = match.Groups["val7"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 7] = match.Groups["val8"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 8] = match.Groups["val9"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 9] = match.Groups["val10"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 10] = match.Groups["val11"].Value;
                dataMatrix[i, 11] = match.Groups["val12"].Value;
```

Here, the value returned by`match.Groups["val2"].Value;` is 96.6 while I expected it to return empty string whereas `match.Groups["val11"].Value;` is empty while I expected it to return 74.8.

The input data are some flow values for corresponding days in each month. So:
[image]
Note that these values are for 2008. So we have a value for 29th Feb.

Answer (score 1):

Wh you not just use the string split method? It takes a char array of delimiters.

Comment: can't use string.split as some of the values would be empty string as is the case for the second value in question above

Comment: Ok gotcha. What is the purpose of the empty spaces? Can you explain a bit more of your purpose with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is unnecessarily complex... Why not use something simpler like:

```
(?:([\w.]+)|(?:\s+))
```

(example: http://regex101.com/r/iN0qD0)

or simpler

```
([\d.]+)
```

(example: http://regex101.com/r/wD7vH7)

It will return arbitrary groups specific to what you want; albeit they're not *named* capture groups, you can determine which ones are which based on their position in the returned match group.

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you're trying to figure out how to retrieve the captures out of this expression, do:

```
dataMatrix[i, 0] = match.Groups[0].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 1] = match.Groups[1].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 2] = match.Groups[2].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 3] = match.Groups[3].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 4] = match.Groups[4].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 5] = match.Groups[5].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 6] = match.Groups[6].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 7] = match.Groups[7].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 8] = match.Groups[8].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 9] = match.Groups[9].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 10] = match.Groups[10].Value;
dataMatrix[i, 11] = match.Groups[11].Value;
```

You could simply this further by implementing a loop like `(from 0 to 11, do)` ...etc.

Comment: I need the value(or empty string) to fill in the variables val1 to val12 so that I can fill in the corresponding matrix...Your regular expresison does not extract them

Comment: @wanderer you're saying you need to include the spaces in the capture? If so, that's even easier (don't need the non-capture groups). That would be `([\w.]+|\s+)`

Comment: Hmmm... looks like I goofed it a bit; hang on.

Comment: @wanderer see update - I think we can get this even simpler, unless you actually need the *number* of spaces between the values.

Comment: used both the above expressions: match.Groups[0].Value and match.Groups[1].Value return 30. Else all the other groups are empty

Comment: Hrm, I don't have a c# dev environment at the moment so I can't get this fine tuned for ya :(

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression worked fine:

```
(?<day>\d{2})\s+(?<val1>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val2>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+|\s{4})\s+(?<val3>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val4>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+|\s{4})\s+(?<val5>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val6>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+|\s{4})\s+(?<val7>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val8>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val9>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+|\s{4})\s+(?<val10>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val11>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+|\s{4})\s+(?<val12>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)
```